# Loading a javascript object from the server into an existing javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am probably not the first one doing this, but I can't find or figure out how to do it.

In my javascript I have an object with 5 properties, which are all object withg data properties and functions.

So it looks like this

```
function Maindata() {
    var obj = this;
    this.id = null;
    this.profile= new Profile();
    this.company= new Company();
    //and more
    this.getid = function(){
        return obj.id;
    };
}
```

and the `profile` and `company` object also has data and functions.

Now I get an object from the server, which is the same object, but only the data, and not the functions.

Now I want to project all of the properties of the retrieved object from the server to my JavaScript object.

I've read to use jQuery Extend, but that doesn't work for me, because it only preserves the functions on the root (Maindata) object, but not on the sub-objects.

How can I load all the data from the subobjects too?

Do I have to $extend the subobjects one by one, like this:

```
$.extend(true, maindata.profile, result.profile);
$.extend(true, maindata.company, result.company);
```

or is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in general - you want to put all functionality *on the prototype* and all data on the object itself:

```
function Maindata() {
    var obj = this;
    this.id = null;
    this.profile= new Profile();
    this.company= new Company();
    //and more
}
Maindata.prototype.getid = function() {
    return this.id;
};
```

The prototype is assigned to every object created with `Maindata` as a constructor and it is *shared* across all `Maindata` instances. So it is likely more efficient and easier to reason about. It's kind of like classes in other languages.

This means you can do:

```
// creates an object with the given prototype without running the constructor
var o = Object.create(Maindata.prototype); 
$.extend(o, result); // copy data over
// Object.assign(o, result); // with ES2015 assign syntax.
```

If your object is nested - then you need to do this in a nested way for subproperties. You can't get types for free since they are not encoded in the JSON. You can implement a custom serializer that does this automatically for you - some libraries like Backbone do this for you but IMO they do a pretty bad job and doing this yourself is pretty straightforward.